# What is prolog query for finding possible values

Tags: prolog

This is my prolog program:

```
par(0,0).
par(0,1).
par(0,2).
par(1,0).
par(1,2).
par(1,1).
par(2,1).
par(2,0).
par(2,2).

gp(X,Y):- par(X,Z),par(Z,Y).

ggp(X,Y) :- par(X,Z), par(Z,W), par(W,Y).
```

What query must be used to obtain he possible set of tuples to satisfy the rules gp and ggp
I tried using gp (X,Y) but doesn't give me the tuples. 
Also gp and ggp are not related. The tuples that satisfy ggp does not have to necessarily satisfy the rule gp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to "pack" the `X` and `Y` together into a tuple, like:

```
tuple_gp((X,Y)) :-
    gp(X,Y).

tuple_ggp((X,Y)) :-
    ggp(X,Y).
```

This then can answer with:

```
?- tuple_gp(T).
T = (0, 0) ;
T = (0, 1) ;
T = (0, 2) ;
T = (0, 0) ;
T = (0, 2) ;
T = (0, 1) ;
T = (0, 1) ;
T = (0, 0) ;
T = (0, 2) ;
T = (1, 0) ;
T = (1, 1) ;
T = (1, 2) ;
T = (1, 1) ;
T = (1, 0) ;
T = (1, 2) ;
T = (1, 0) ;
T = (1, 2) ;
T = (1, 1) ;
T = (2, 0) ;
T = (2, 2) ;
T = (2, 1) ;
T = (2, 0) ;
T = (2, 1) ;
T = (2, 2) ;
T = (2, 1) ;
T = (2, 0) ;
T = (2, 2).
```

If you want to generate a *list* of all possible tuples, you can use `findall/3`:

```
?- findall((X,Y),gp(X,Y),L).
L = [ (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (..., ...)|...].

?- findall((X,Y),ggp(X,Y),L).
L = [ (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (..., ...)|...].
```

If you want only to obtain *unique* tuples, you can use `setof/3`:

```
?- setof((X,Y),X^Y^gp(X,Y),S).
S = [ (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (..., ...)].
```

Comment: Ok thank u very much. I have one more doubt. What if I want to find the tuples that only produces gp(0,1) and ggp(1,2) ..

Comment: What do you mean the tuples that only produce `gp(0,1)` and `ggp(1,2)`? A predicate does *not* produces anything... A predicate is only `true` or `false` (or triggers an error).

Comment: Out of the given facts like par(0,0), par(0,1).... assuming you have only the rule gp, how can we determine what combinations in the par() would give me the gp tuple as (0,1)

Comment: @confucious: AFAIK you can not (definitely not without doing some inpure logic), since usually a predicate is considered a *blackbox*.

Comment: hmm alright . I thought so. From what I did by hand (theoretically) ,only par combinations of  " (0,1) (1,1)" and "(0,2) (2,1)" will produce me (0,1) for gp .. So I wanted to look for a query that can give me this

Comment: @confucious: well you can of course remove all the `par/2` facts, and only ad the `par(0,1)`, `par(1,1)`, `par(0,2)` and `par(2,0)` as new facts.